# Where is the String Receiving Part in this Code? (Bluetooth chat Application)

Tags: android, string, listview, bluetooth

I just need to Modify the **Bluetooth Chat Application**.  The String will be Successfully Received in **ListView** , but i don't have an idea to Where is the **String Receiving Part** Processing in below Code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et_tnum;
    private EditText et_pass;
    private TextView status;
    private Button btnConnect;
    private ListView listView;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> chatAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> chatMessages;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final String DEVICE_OBJECT = "device_name";

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private ChatController chatController;
    private BluetoothDevice connectingDevice;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevicesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewsByIds();

        //check device support bluetooth or not
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        //show bluetooth devices dialog when click connect button
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPrinterPickDialog();
            }
        });

        //set chat adapter
        chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chatMessages);
        listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setStatus("Connected to: " + connectingDevice.getName());
                            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                        case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            setStatus("Connecting...");
                            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                        case ChatController.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case ChatController.STATE_NONE:
                            setStatus("Not connected");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    chatMessages.add("Me: " + writeMessage);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    chatMessages.add(connectingDevice.getName() + ":  " + readMessage);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT:
                    connectingDevice = msg.getData().getParcelable(DEVICE_OBJECT);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectingDevice.getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString("toast"),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

private void showPrinterPickDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bluetooth);
    dialog.setTitle("Bluetooth Devices");

    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    //Initializing bluetooth adapters
    ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    discoveredDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    //locate listviews and attatch the adapters
    ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
    ListView listView2 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.discoveredDeviceList);
    listView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesAdapter);
    listView2.setAdapter(discoveredDevicesAdapter);

    // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            pairedDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    } else {
        pairedDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_paired));
    }

    //Handling listview item click event
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            connectToDevice(address);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            connectToDevice(address);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

private void setStatus(String s) {
    status.setText(s);
}

private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
    chatController.connect(device);
}

private void findViewsByIds() {
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    et_tnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_tnum);
    et_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass);
    View btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

}


  btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 { @Override
  public void onClick(View view)
  { String number =et_tnum.getText().toString();
  String password=et_pass.getText().toString();
  if (et_pass.getText().toString().equals(""))
  { Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
  else {
  String numberpass= "Account Number:"+number+"\nPassword:"+password;
  sendMessage(numberpass);
  et_pass.setText("");
  }
  }
  });



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth still disabled, turn off application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
     }
 }

 private void sendMessage(String message) {
     if (chatController.getState() != ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection was lost!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
     }

     if (message.length() > 0) {
         byte[] send = message.getBytes();
         chatController.write(send);
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
         Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
         startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
     } else {
         chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     if (chatController != null) {
         if (chatController.getState() == ChatController.STATE_NONE) {
             chatController.start();
         }
     }
 }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatController != null)
            chatController.stop();

    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    String recieverAddress = device.getName();
                    String recieverPassword = device.getAddress();
                    et_tnum.setText(recieverAddress);
                    et_pass.setText(recieverPassword);
                }
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_found));
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="348dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Not Connected" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_connect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Connect" />
</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="332dp"
    android:layout_height="164dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_tnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Account Number"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="213dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="verify" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's at

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
                //read recieved data
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                //convert recieved data to String
                //readMessage is your String where the recieved message is saved
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                chatMessages.add(connectingDevice.getName() + ":  " + readMessage);
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
```

Comment: can i receive those strings inside the edittext instead of r listview??

Comment: you need `ListView` cause you have multiple received messages and for better readability, for putting it at `TextView` or `EditText` you use `myTextVIew.append("\n "+ readMessage);` the `\n` is used to return to line

Comment: thanks a lot!!!  but my problem is i need to receive those inside edittext. i dont knw how to do.any idea sir